# Android compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs

Tags: android, build.gradle

Dependency 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-beta02' requires libraries and applications that depend on it to compile against version 33 or later of the Android APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Just update in `app/build.gradle`

1- compileSdk to 33

2- targetSdk to 33

check the following code

```
android {
    compileSdk 33
   
...

    defaultConfig {

...
        targetSdk 33

    }
}
```

Comment: `defaultConfig` belongs to `android`, so first closing bracket `}`, this one after `compileSdk`, shouldn't be there